# Select top n% of the records from each group based on the column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a use case where I need to select top n% of the rows based on the column value

Example:

```
Id | Group Name  | Value  
1  |   *Group 1*   | 10  
2  |   Group 2   | 20  
3  |   *Group 1*   | 5  
4  |   *Group 1*   | 100  
5  |   Group 2   | 10  
6  |   *Group 1*   | 150
```

From each group, I need to select the top 40% of rows based on the value
In the case of group 1 total value is 265
40% of 265 = 106

So anything greater than 106 should be returned in group 1 as a result

Comment: If you want the top 40%, shouldn't that be anything up-to and including 106?

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(value) over (partition by groupname) as total,
             sum(value) over (partition by groupname order by value desc) as running
      from t
     ) t
where running - value < 0.4 * total;
```

This returns the first row that *exceeds* 40%.  If you want the last row before that, then use:

```
where running < 0.4 * total;
```